# Set the IP address in J2ME

Tags: java-me

how can I set a custom IP address programmatically in J2ME. For eg. I want to set last two bytes to some random number and first two bytes some fixed number viz. 162.3.

Comment: ehh, the title implies you want to "set" the IP on the device, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`random.nextInt(int limit);`

hope this will help you.